# Looking for examples or guides or links to understand JAX-WS 1.2 project

Tags: web-services, websphere, cxf, jax-ws

> I have got an opportunity to work on a legacy web service project
>   which has been written 10 to 12 years before . I happily took this
>   assignment as i really wanted to check out how much effort the
>   developers had put decades before to write web services without the
>   advanced framework which we have nowadays . I really think they had
>   put a lot !!! coz the pkg has so many classes which i dont even
>   understand what is it ... It has BO ,PO , WSAO classes , CXF mapping ,
>   marshalling and unmarshalling  .. So i want help from senior
>   developers here who have worked on web services decades before coz i
>   couldn't find any example in net really , all seems to be archived or
>   Page not found link .so please provide me any links or examples to
>   understand JAX-WS 1.2 , Webservice client - service . It might not be
>   a coding question but a question which would really others who are
>   willing to work on legacy projects .Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You might start with just the "spec" jax-ws classes first.  Various implementations have a lot of other, non-spec features that aren't portable and go beyond the spec, I'd save those for later.  There are parts of jax-ws that are "off the beaten path", (handlers, low level api's, attachments, etc.) you can save those for later too.

This might be a good place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html

Java 6 through 8 contains jax-ws (unfortunately it's removed starting with java11) so you don't need an app server to experiment with it, just a java 8 jdk.

This seems to be a pretty good article on using jax-ws with just a jdk:
https://www.javaworld.com/article/3215966/web-services-in-java-se-part-2-creating-soap-web-services.html

The spec, JSR-224, is a good explanation, but it's not light reading, and you have to accept their license.
 https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224

Comment: Thank you so much . Do you have any idea of what these PO, WSAO and BO classes .. I have came across VO and DAO classes .. but i dont get what these implies

Comment: Not really, there were a lot of "add ons" to base webservices - transactions, reliable messaging, addressing, etc. They usually had their own specs, WS-(something).  Then there were the implementations that "did their own thing" alongside jax-ws with no specs.  It was a time of specs run amok, imho.  If you can figure which impl you're on, that might help.  Apache Axis2, CXF, and Metro were some of the more popular ones.